# How to display the listbox without horizontal lines using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

am trying to display the listbox with out horizontal lines inside that
by using bootswrap listbox.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet"    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">

  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">First item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Second item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Third item</li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
```

But it is displaying with horizontal lines.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ta8h32oz/)

Please let me know how to display the listbox with out lines.It would be like  below screen.

[image]

Comment: Please let us know about your researches so far...

Comment: If you don’t like the borders bootstrap applies, then overwrite them …

Answer (score 1):

From the Bootstrap css-file:

```
list-group-item {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
```

The `border: 1px solid #ddd` creates your border. You can overwrite that by creating your own css file (or in your .html). Link it **after** the Bootstrap css in your header! If you link it first the Bootstrap css would overwrite your changes. Otherwise you could also add `!important` to your changes.

In your css:

```
list-group-item {
    border: 0px;
    }
```

Everything about Bootstrap, css, html, js,... is very well documented and explained at http://www.w3schools.com/. It will most likely answer all your questions!

Answer (score 0):

Override the bootstrap css to something like this

```
.list-group-item:first-child {
     border-top-left-radius: 4px;
     border-top-right-radius: 4px;
     border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.list-group-item {
     position: relative;
     display: block;
     padding: 10px 15px;
     margin-bottom: -1px;
     background-color: #fff;
     border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
     border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.list-group-item:last-child {
     margin-bottom: 0;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Updated Fiddle : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ta8h32oz/2/)

Add these styles in any css file (for example : custom.css). Then link your custom.css file below the bootstrap.css. Custom.css style definitions will override bootstrap.css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: i added the code in bootswrap.css file,but styles are not effecting.Don't know wt happen

Comment: You need to link the css file after the bootstrap.css file gets loaded. In this way, it gets overriden. Please find the updated answer.

Comment: I have loaded the custom.css file after  the bootstrap.css and added  2 links in my html file. But styles are not effecting. Please let me know..

Comment: Can you please create a plunker or jsfiddle to look into the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, here I have demonstrated both with border and without border using toggleClass.
You can drag and drop any element and on clicking arrow entire list will get shifted.

```js
$.fn.changeTag = function(tag){
                   // create the new, empty shim
                   var replacement = $('<' + tag + '>');
                   // empty container to hold attributes
                   var attributes = {};
                   // copy all the attributes to the shell
                   $.each(this.get(0).attributes, function(index, attribute) {
                       attributes[attribute.name] = attribute.value;
                   }); 
                   // assign attributes to replacement
                   replacement.attr(attributes);
                   // copy the data
                   replacement.data(this.data());
                   // get all the kids, with data and events
                   var contents = this.children().clone(true);
                   // inseminate
                   replacement.append(contents);
                   // swap it out
                   this.replaceWith(replacement);
                }
    
                var $chooser = $("#fieldChooser").fieldChooser();
                var $sourceFields = $("#sourceFields").children();
                $chooser.getSourceList().add($sourceFields);
                
                
                
                document.getElementById("toggleBorder").onclick=function(){
                $('.list-group-item').toggleClass('noboder');
                };
                $('.list-group-item').toggleClass('noboder');
                $("#fieldChooser").append("<td id=\"source\"></td>");
   $("#fieldChooser").append($("#mover"));
   $('#mover').changeTag('td');
   $("#fieldChooser").append("<td id=\"destination\"></td>");

$("#source").append($(".fc-source-fields"));
$("#destination").append($(".fc-destination-fields"));
                document.getElementById("moveleft").onclick=function(){
                $(".fc-source-fields").append($(".fc-destination-fields .list-group-item"));
                };
                document.getElementById("moveright").onclick=function(){
                $(".fc-destination-fields").append($(".fc-source-fields .list-group-item"));
                };
                $('fieldChooser div.fc-field-list').addClass( "list-group" );
```

```css
.noboder, .noboder:hover{
    margin: 0px;
    border-width: 0px !important;
    box-shadow:unset !important;
    outline:unset !important;
  }
  .list-group-item {
    white-space: nowrap;
      padding:5px !important;
  }
  #moveleft,#moveright,.list-group-item  {
    cursor:hand;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
  table{
   margin:auto;
  }
  td.list-group{
   border:1px solid #777; 
   padding:1px;
   margin:0px !important;
   
  }
th {
  text-align:center !important;
  }
#mover{
  padding:0px !important;
  margin:0px !important;
}
.fc-field-list{
  height:300px !important;
  overflow:auto !important;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Drag-Drop-Multi-Select-List-Box-fieldChooser/demo/stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Drag-Drop-Multi-Select-List-Box-fieldChooser/fieldChooser.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul id="sourceFields" class="list-group">
<li class="list-group-item">First name</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Last name</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Home</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Work</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Direct</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Cell</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Fax</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Work email</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Personal email</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Website</li>
</ul>
<div id="mover" style="width: 50px;text-align: center;color:#1D65B1;">
    <span id="moveleft" class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true" title="Move all left"></span>
    <span id="moveright" class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true" title="Move all right"></span>
            
</div>

<table>
            <tr>
            <th>Store List</th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Store Selection</th>
            </tr>
<tr id="fieldChooser" class="list-group" tabIndex="1"></tr>
</table>

<input type="button" id="toggleBorder" value="Toggle Border" >
```

Comment: Errors are coming while running the code snippet..Can you please check.